# Rearrange the order of nodes in a sankey diagram using ggsankey

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, sankey-diagram

I did a sankey diagram in R using the ggsankey package and everything is fine, only detail is I want to rearrenge the order of the nodes in the second level (right now it is arranged SD, PR, DP, and CR from top to bottom and i want them to appear CR, PR, SD, DP from top to bottom). Is there a way to customize the position?

[image]

This is the code i used to generate the plot

```
devtools::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
library(ggsankey)

sankey_df <- base_limpia%>% transmute(
  Treatment = Type.of.Treatment,
  Response = Respuesta,
  Transplantation = Post_therapy_trasplantation
)

sankey_df <- sankey_df %>% make_long(Treatment,
                                     Response,
                                     Transplantation
)

reagg <- sankey_df%>%
  dplyr::group_by(node)%>%  # Here we are grouping the data by node and then we are taking the frequency of it 
  tally()

sankey_df2 <- merge(sankey_df,
             reagg, 
             by.x = 'node', 
             by.y = 'node', 
             all.x = TRUE)
png(file = "Figure 6.png", width = 3200, height = 2000, res = 300)
plot <- ggplot(sankey_df2, aes(x = x,                        
                     next_x = next_x,                                     
                     node = node,
                     next_node = next_node,        
                     fill = factor(node),
                     label = paste0(node, " = ", n)))

plot <- plot + geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5,          
                      node.color = "black",        
                      show.legend = F) + 
  geom_sankey_label(size = 3,
                    color = "black",
                    fill = "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Comment: Sankey automatically re-orders data to minimise overlap.  I don't believe you can override it without messing with the ggplot object diretly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your dataset so I can't exactly check if this will work, but it worked for me when I wanted to change the order: Change the node and/or next_node to a factor and set the factor levels manually.

See this example from github:

```
dflong$node <- factor(dflong$node,levels = c("C","B","A"))
dflong$next_node <- factor(dflong$next_node,levels = c("C","B","A"))

dflong %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = x, 
              next_x = next_x, 
              node = node, 
              next_node = next_node,
              fill = factor(node),
              value = value)) +
  geom_sankey()
```

This worked for me since my data also had the same levels for node and next_node, like in the example.

Comment: This worked for me as well.   A little confusingly, order is applied from the bottom of the plot up, as implied by Justin's example above.  So my understanding is the first level in your factor will be at the bottom of your plot.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to @PGSA above, I highly doubt that ggsankey is auto-ordering things to minimize overlap, since in the OP's graph, all three columns are in alphabetical order from bottom to top.  This happens in my own plots as well.  It's just using the factor order and using R's typical default of alphabetizing the levels to determine the factor ordering.

Comment: Hello John, thanks for using StackOverflow. To reply to someone, please add a comment, not an answer.